# Core data managed object property retention

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, core-data

I seem to be having an issue with my managed objects not releasing memory.  I have an NSOperation that downloads new information, saves it to a temp context, then merges it to the main context.  All this works well but in the allocations instrument all the newly created properties stick around in memory after the merge is complete and the entire operation is deallocated. Is there any way to fix this?  I've tried to reset both the temp and main contexts and refreshObject:, both don't fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: Pretty tricky to debug without looking at your code.  What happens if you simulate a memory warning in the simulator?  Also, are you using an undo manager with your context?

Comment: It's standard code for adding managed objects.  Memory warnings don't clear the allocated objects and the context's undo manager is set to nil

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you create an `NSAutoreleasePool` first thing in the operations `main`. Before you return out of main make sure you `drain` the pool. This includes returns before the end of the method such as inside an if statement.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I forgot to mention that I tried this to no avail.  It's only the objects properties that aren't being released, not the objects.  I've not allocated these myself either and are created by foundation.